# Can I use Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2008 for creating commercial product?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I search everywhere for finding information about license of Crystal Report. But I can't find anything. I have a few questions for Crystal Report 2008 for Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

1. What's license of Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2008 SP1?
2. What's different between Crystal Report runtime & Crystal Report server?
3. What's limit of Crystal Report for Visual Studio?

Moreover, I found some software that use Crystal Report files as template file. So, I think that Crystal Report editor isn't free. But Crystal Report runtime is free.

**Update - Component Engine Redistribution Licensing**

> Both the .Net and Java runtime engine
>   are considered component engines, as
>   they run in-process with a hosting
>   application.
>
> Thick client applications for internal
>   and external use: When these component
>   engines are embedded into thick client
>   applications, they may be freely
>   distributed both internally and
>   externally to third parties.
>
> Web applications for internal use:
>   When these component engines are
>   embedded into Web applications, they
>   may be freely distributed internally
>   only.

[Report Viewer for Crystal Reports](http://reportviewer.biz/)

[Crystal Reports for Visual Studio .NET License Agreement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288179(VS.71).aspx)

[How to deploy the Crystal Reports 2008 Basic Runtime](http://weblogs.asp.net/guybarrette/archive/2008/04/24/how-to-deploy-the-crystal-reports-2008-basic-runtime.aspx)

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 1):

> USE AND DISTRIBUTION OF RUNTIME
>   SOFTWARE. 
>   4.1   Deployment and Distribution of Client Applications. Crystal Decisions
>   grants you a personal, nonexclusive,
>   limited license to deploy, reproduce
>   and distribute Client Applications to
>   end users, if you comply with all of
>   the terms of this license agreement,
>   including section 4.4.

Yes, you can use it for commercial apps, and the runtime and report viewer are free to distribute within your app.  Just read, understand, and follow the rest of the terms.

Comment: But it's a performance limited edition. Moreover, from section 4.3,  This license agreement does not in itself give you any right to distribute Server/Web Applications to third parties. So, I can't use in commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

I remember delving through all of the license terms of Crystal Reports Developer Edition. I came to the following conclusion:

You can create client apps. That means you can create Windows Forms / WPF applications that have Crystal Reports hosted in the windows, and distribute the applications freely.

You might want to create a *server* app, where the reports are generated by your ASP.NET application. In this case, the customer must purchase one Crystal Reports licencse.

---

Caveat: This is my *recollection*, which might help clarify things. It might be wrong, and if it is I'm not responsible and you shouldn't rely on legal advice given by strangers over the internet yada yada yada. I'm sure you know that.

Comment: Do you know about performance limited edition? Can you estimate performance between Visual Studio edition and non-performance limited edition?