# How does Crystal Reports Runtime Licensing work?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, licensing, software-distribution

I am designing an application in C# and I want to use some Crystal Reports in my application. I am selling this application as freelance to a small business. This is my first program that I have ever sold. I have Crystal Reports 2008 that I am using to design reports with. Do I need to get any kind of licensing from Business Objects to include the Crystal Reports Runtime for report printing in my application? Or do I not need to worry about it as long as I have a licensed version of Crystal Reports 2008 on my development machine.

The client would only need be able to print the reports that I have designed on my machine, not design their own. The reports would be saved as a file. The application will load the saved report and print it with provided data.

I did see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475235/can-i-use-crystal-report-for-visual-studio-2008-for-creating-commercial-product) which answers the most part of my question. However, it does not include whether it covers loading saved report documents?

Any additional related information for a commercial product newbie is gladly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to SAP's website, by purchasing a license to Crystal Reports 2008 you are allowed to distribute the runtime along with your application without further licensing.  Your product would be considered a *thick client application for external use*, meaning the entities using the software would not be a part of your organization.

From SAP's website regarding licensing:

> Thick client applications for internal
>   and external use: When these component
>   engines are embedded into thick client
>   applications, **they may be freely
>   distributed both internally and
>   externally to third parties**. *(emphasis mine)*

[Source: SAP Crystal Reports Licensing Information](http://www.dataaccess.com/KBasePublic/Files/2463.CR_Licensing.pdf)

This is not very different from CR XI's redistribution license, but in CR XI you had to have the development edition to legally redistribute the runtime to a third party.  They seem to have simplified this considerably.

Comment: link is down, is it possible to update it?